# Usar mod_rewrite para enmascarar URL hacia lector pdf.js de Mozilla

Tags: javascript, pdf, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reescritura-url

En mi sitio web tengo el lector pdf.js de Mozilla (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) y estoy tratando de implementar mod_rewrite en el .htaccess del directorio raíz con dos propósitos:

1. Para enmascarar la URL hacia el lector y así evitar que los usuarios traten de adivinar el directorio donde se guardan los archivos PDF.
2. Si el usuario llega a localizar el directorio donde se guardan los archivos PDF, al tratar de acceder que sean redirigidos hacia otra URL.

Para esto estoy usando 4 archivos:

1. El .htaccess con el mod_rewrite, que está en la carpeta raíz de https://www.misitio.com/
2. La página que tiene el link hacia el lector de PDF, que está en https://www.misitio.com/lista.php
3. El lector de PDF, que está en https://www.misitio.com/lector/desktop/web/index.php
4. El archivo PDF, que está en https://www.misitio.com/lector/desktop/web/biblioteca/libro01.pdf

Normalmente la URL para acceder al lector y que este cargue el archivo PDF es: https://www.misitio.com/lector/desktop/web/index.php?file=biblioteca/libro01.pdf

Lo que estoy poniendo en el .htaccess, para enmascarar la URL es:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*    
RewriteRule ^leer/(*.)$ lector/desktop/web/index.php?file=biblioteca/$1
```

El link que estoy colocando en lista.php es:

```
<a href="leer/libro01.pdf">ENTRAR</a>
```

Al acceder desde el navegador sí me muestra la URL: https://www.misitio.com/leer/libro01.pdf

Pero no carga el lector, en vez de eso me muestra el error 404 Not Found.

Quiero resolver este primer punto de enmascarar la URL antes de pasar al segundo punto, ya le he dado muchas vueltas al asunto y no logro ver donde me estoy equivocando, hasta estoy sospechando que el lector de Mozilla no permite el uso del mod_rewrite, jajaja.

¿Qué me aconsejan ajustar?, se los agradezco de antemano.